# C#/WinForms tooltip stops displaying

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm facing the following issue during setting up tooltips on a WinForms / C# desktop application (using .NET Framework version 4.5).
Application has hundreds of form elements where I would like to display a tooltip.

Current implementation as the following:

- I have one toolTip object on my main form
- Language file has been loaded and saved in an array
- There is a method which suppose to assign the tooltip texts to the different elements accordingly by calling the SetToolTip method on the toolTip object.

E.g.

```
toolTip.SetToolTip(backBtn, LocalizationFile[0]);
toolTip.SetToolTip(myTextBox, LocalizationFile[1]);
```

It works fine, tooltips are displayed correctly.
As soon as I reach ca. 30 calls it stops working.
Calling ~30 times SetToolTip method to setup the required tooltips, cause to completely stop displaying the tooltips.
The previously worked tooltip texts are not getting display anymore.
There is no exception or any error message.

Can you please explain me why the toolTip object just stops displaying the texts after calling the SetToolTip method several times? Is there any workaround out there to apply in such cases?

**EDIT-1**
**Following workaround** works, but I'm still unsure what is the original problem.
I have created a method to call SetToolTip on the toolTip object, after calling the method, I re-create the toolTip instance using the "new" operator. That solves the issue. However as I want to disable anytime the tooltips on my application I also store all the references in a List. On that list I can iterate over to enable / disable all toolTip references according to what the user wants.
Basically there is a button to toggle the tooltips.

Do you have any idea, why this actually solves the original issue?

```
    List<ToolTip> storeToolTipReferences = new List<ToolTip>(); //store tooltip references
    //method begin called to set the tooltip on a control, store the reference of the tooltip and create a new instance
    private void SetMyToolTip(Control ctrl, string toolTipText)
    {
        toolTip.SetToolTip(ctrl, toolTipText);
        storeToolTipReferences.Add(toolTip);

        toolTip = new ToolTip();
    }
    
    
    //called as the application loads or the user changes the language
    private void SetAppLanguage(string[] LocalizationText)
    {

        storeToolTipReferences.ForEach(e => e.RemoveAll());
        SetMyToolTip(ctrl1, LocalizationText[1]);
        SetMyToolTip(ctrl2, LocalizationText[2]);
        SetMyToolTip(ctrl3, LocalizationText[3]);
        .....
    }
        
    //logic for tooltip enable/disable in my application
    storeToolTipReferences.ForEach(t => t.Active = tooltip_control.Checked);
```

Thank you!

Comment: Could you please explain what is need for setting it 30 times? I would also suggest to check LocalizationFile[1], if this is returning correct data after 30 times

Comment: Suppose you have 100 elements on your application. So how do you setup the tooltip to each element? I would call the SetToolTip method 100 times on a tooltip object. The array LocalizationFile has all the necessary localization texts, it does not matter how i handle localiazation here. Point is, as I keep adding the line "toolTip.SetToolTip(..)" it stops working after ~ 30 calls. Why?